# US dollar amount, thousands separated by commas

Tags: python, regex, currency

I'm new to python. I am trying to extract an amount denominated in US dollars from a sub-string using a regex expression. It works for the most part, however I'm faced with a couple of issues that I haven't been able to get around.

The resulting amount is a string not recognized as an amount because of the commas. It also doesn't work for small amounts less than `$1`, (ex. `0.89`). There is no leading `$`. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is what I have:

```
df['Amount']=df['description'].str.extract('(\d{1,3}?(\,\d{3})*\.\d{2})')
```

Here is a string that should be parsed:

```
000000000463 NYC DOF OPA CONCENTRATION ACCT. *00029265 07/01/2013 AP5378 1,107,844.38 Ven000000000463 Vch:00029265
```

I'm trying to extract the amount `1,107,844.38` in a separate column of a dataframe object. I don't have any strings that should be rejected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try a regex like

```
rx = r"\b(?<!/)(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*(?:\.\d{2})?)\b(?!/)"
df['Amount']=df['description'].str.extract(rx)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ET86am/1)

**Details**

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?<!/)` - no `/` immediately to the left of the current location (to avoid matching date time values)
- `\d{1,3}` - 1 to 3 digits
- `(?:,\d{3})*` - 0+ repetitions of `,` and 3 digits
- `(?:\.\d{2})?` - an optional `.` and 2 digits
- `\b` - a word boundary
- `(?!/)` - no `/` immediately to the right of the current location (to avoid matching date time values)

Answer (score 0):

Given your example string:

```
"000000000463 NYC DOF OPA CONCENTRATION ACCT. *00029265 07/01/2013 AP5378 1,107,844.38 Ven000000000463 Vch:00029265"
```

Here's what I have come up with:

```
match = re.search(r"(?P<amount>\$?(?:\d+,)*\d+\.\d+)", subject)
if match:
    result = match.group("amount")  # result will be "1,107,844.38"
else:
    result = ""
```

to extract the amount. It also handles small amounts like `0.38`, amounts that have no thousand separator commas like `123456789.38`, and amounts may or may not be preceeded by a dollar sign `$`.

**Regex details**

```
(?<amount>\$?(?:\d+,)*\d+\.\d+)  Match the regular expression below and capture its match into backreference with name “amount” 
\$?                              Match the character “$” literally
?                                Between zero and one times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) 
(?:\d+,)*                        Match the regular expression below 
*                                Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) 
\d+                              Match a single digit 0..9 
+                                Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy) 
,                                Match the character “,” literally 
\d+                              Match a single digit 0..9 
+                                Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
\.                               Match the character “.” literally 
\d+                              Match a single digit 0..9 
+                                Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
```